# Does column name length count for each cell size when counting the column size in Google bigquery?

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery

I know in HBase for example, you need to put column names as small as possible to minimize the size.

Is it the same in google bigquery? Should I put column names as small as possible?

Answer (score 3):

Good news: In BigQuery you don't need to worry about the column names length. Be as descriptive as you'd like to, since the column name is part of the table description, and not of each record.